# I have view port quality issue (Sorry if this has been asked before I couldn't find an answer)

Tags: 3d-view, performance

[image: Fuzzy/Choppy Edges]

The image shows my problem it has Choppy edges in the viewport. I looked all over google and this forum but could not find a solution. I have an RTX 2080 and i7 8900k.

I fixed it once by creating a new workspace "Layout" and it worked all day but the next day I got on it was like this again.

I hope I can get a quick fix for this. 
Thank you.

Comment: probably it doesnt has a material? can you put more captures of the full window?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out.
It was the camera clipping start length, it was set to low it doesn't like it when you just drag it to the lowest point.

like in this image [image]